# Make windows open with work with my application

Tags: windows, open-with

I wrote an application which will be able to open files of particular extension and show it to users. Now I want the users to be able to just double click the file and have it open with my application. I tried to set the "Always use the selected program..." option in the windows "Open With" dialog box, but do not know how to receive the file name that Windows sends to my application. How to do this?

Thanks...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706538/event-to-handle-open-with-winapi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name will be passed to your application as an argument. 
For example, in c#, you will get it like this:

```
static class Program

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  if (args.Length > 0)
  {
    string filename = args[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you need something like:

```
~ Notepad test.txt
```

So, you need to make an optional argument in your application. If it exists open the file. If not, open a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the filename in your application's startup parameters

Answer (score 0):

Windows passes the filename as a startup parameter to your application. You will need to handle this in your WinMain or application entry point.